# glBuffer with heap memory

Tags: c++, opengl

I have run into an issue I am unsure of how to properly handle. I recently began creating a particle system for my game, and have been using a structure called 'Particle' for my particle data. 'Particle' contains the vertex information for rendering.

The reason I am having issues is that I am pooling my particle structures in heap memory in order to save on large amounts of allocations, however I am unsure of how to use an array of pointers in glBufferData, I am under the impression that glBufferData requires the actual structure instance rather then a pointer to the structure instance.

I know I can rebuild an array of floats each render just to draw my particles, but is there an OpenGL call like glBufferData which I am missing somewhere that is able to de-reference my pointers as it is going through the data I supply? I would ideally like to prevent having to iterate over the array just to copy the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am under the impression that glBufferData requires the actual structure instance rather then a pointer to the structure instance.

Correct. Effectively `glBufferData` creates a flat copy of the data preseted to it at the address pointed it via the *data* parameter.

> which I am missing somewhere that is able to de-reference my pointers as it is going through the data I supply?

You're thinking of client side vertex arrays, and those are among the oldest features of OpenGL. They're around since OpenGL-1.1, released 19 years ago.

You just *don't* use a buffer object, i.e. don't call glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData and pass your client side data address directly to glVertexPointer or glVertexAttribPointer.

However I strongly advise to actually use buffer objects. The data must be copied to the GPU anyway, so that it can be rendered. And doing it through a buffer object enables the OpenGL driver to work more efficiently. Also since OpenGL-4 the use of buffer objects is no longer optional.

Comment: I actually figured out how to do what I wanted to do, I mapped the buffer to a pointer and filled it myself, I don't wan't to use any old features as I would much rather learn how to do things the new way.

Comment: @user1294021: Well, mapping a buffer is not really heap memory. It's a part of the GPUs system swap memory mapped into your process' address space. Also you must unmap the buffer before you can draw from it.

Comment: Yup I unmapped as well thanks, is this the most efficient way to do this? It's mostly that I need to deference my pointers so I can pass data into the buffer.